# Pyomo optimization problem, problem with index

Tags: python, optimization, indexing, pyomo

I am trying to optimize power generation and minimize costs in python with pyomo package.
I take the parameters from Matpower case, right now I am trying case5.

So usually, I would put:

```
m.Gen=Var(m.N, domain = NonNegativeReals) 
m.Pg=Var(m.N, domain = Reals)
m.N  = Set(initialize=[i for i in range(bus_number)])

def obj_rule(m):
    cost =  sum(Cg[n]*m.Gen[n] for n in m.N )
    return    cost 
m.obj = Objective(rule = obj_rule, sense=minimize)

def loadbal_rule(m, n):
    return Sb*  m.pg[n] == -m.gen[n] + Pd[n] 
m.loadbal_rule = Constraint(m.N, rule = loadbal_rule)
```

Here, n is the nodes in the system. The load-balance ensures that there is enough power delivered to each node. Pd[n] is the demand of power at node n. N is the total number of nodes. Sb is base power, pg[n] is the power injected in node n (can be from any other node that is connected to it)
I also have constraints for the power flows from one node to another but I dont show them here (that's why I cannot just put sum(gen[n] for n in m.N) == sum( Pd[n] for n in m.N)

Now to my problem:
In case 5, there are 5 nodes, and two generators at node 1, but no generators at node 2. Therefore, I think I need an index for generators, g in m.G?

But then, I don't know how to formulate the objective function and the load balance. should it be m.gen[g,n]?

This is what I tried:

```
def obj_rule(m):
    cost =  sum(Cg[g]*(m.gen[g,n]) for g in m.G for n in m.N) 
    return    cost  
m.obj = Objective(rule = obj_rule, sense=minimize)

def loadbal_rule(m, n,g):
    return Sb*  m.pg[n] == sum(m.gen[n,g] for g in m.G) - Pd_matrix[n] # ??  
m.loadbal_rule = Constraint(m.N, m.G, rule = loadbal_rule)
```

Comment: I don't think there is enough info here to answer your question.  If you don't need to account for each generator individually, why can't you just "double" the max generation for Node 1?  Presumably, you have a constraint to limit the generation to the max output, which is a param in your model, no?  so then: `max_gen = {1:20, 2:0, 3:10, 4:10, ...}`

Comment: That does not work because they are different types of generators

Answer (score 0):

OK, so if you can't just treat both generators at node 1 as grouped together (as I suggested in the comment), I think you have 2 choices....

You could double-index your decision variables for node x generator [n, g] as you attempted to do.  If you do that, you can initialize the variable with a sparse set of the legal combinations of [n, g] that you should generate from the data.  Then in your load balance, you need to formulate that *for each node* not *for each node-gen combo* as you seem to be doing now.  You still wan the power to balance at the node, so sum across the generators internally....  something like:

```
def node_load_bal(m, n):
    return m.pg[n] == sum(m.gen[n, g] for g in m.G) - m.pd[n]
m.load_bal = Constraint(m.N, rule=node_load_bal)
```

The other option, which is probably more clever and simple in that it avoids the double indexing is to introduce a fake (or synthetic) node to accommodate the extra generator.  Call it node "1B" or something, and connect it **logically** (no demand, properly connected to node 1, etc.) to the "real" node 1 and then just run everything you already have on the N+1 nodes.